# How to update annotations from fields values to annotations objects

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, annotation

I have annotations feature class and need to update some field offset and alignment values

When I edits them manually at attributes table in ArcMap, new values applies to objects and they changes thrir positions at map.

And when I updates them via script:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(annotations_fc, ['VerticalAlignment', 'YOffset']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = 3
        row[1] = 2.0
        cursor.updateRow(row)

del cursor
```

attributes table has new values but these values doesn't apply to map objects

Arcpy has `UpdateAnnotation_management` method for annotations updating. But as I understand, it updates field values from annotation objects when I needs reverse action - update annotation objects from fields values.

Is such method exist? If not in arcpy, at least in arcobjects.net?

Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's an arcpy bug - arcobjects.net code processes annotaton features perfectly.

```cs
IFeatureCursor cursor = featureClass.Update(null, false);

int vAlignField = featureClass.Fields.FindField("VerticalAlignment");
int yOffsetField = featureClass.Fields.FindField("YOffset");

IFeature feature = cursor.NextFeature();
while (feature != null)
{
    IPolygon4 poly = (IPolygon4)feature.Shape;
    IRing ring = new RingClass();
    poly.QueryExteriorRings(ref ring);
    feature.Value[vAlignField] = 3;
    feature.Value[yOffsetField] = 2.0;
    feature.Store();
    feature = cursor.NextFeature();
}
```

Annotation objects are shifted after code running as I expected.